# OnClickListener listens only on the second time

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText and have added an onClickListener to it. In the click method I am just clearing the text. When I click the editText first time the keypad pops up. But it is not going into the onClick method. The second time when I click it it is called and clears the text.

```
qtyEditTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.qtyet);
qtyEditTxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                qtyEditTxt.setText("");             
            }
        });
```

I saw a question with an answer stating to make android:focusableInTouchMode to false. But then I will not be able to enter the text. Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about focus?

```
final EditText qtyEditTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtyet);
qtyEditTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean isFocus) 
    {
        if (isFocus)
        {
            qtyEditTxt.setText("");             
        }
    }
});
```

Edited:

Default text? There you go :)

```
android:hint="Enter Quantity"
```

Comment: its working thanks.... My previous comment saying i need onClick rather than focus was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

ClickListener is not a good choice for editText . use

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<requestFocus />` right after closing tag of EditText in your layout.xml file