# fragment callback using interface

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` that starts a `Fragmen`t. Inside that fragment i have an `EditText`. And when i get the text that the user types there, i want to get that from my `Activity` with the help of an `interface`. I'm using [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

On my `MainActivity` i'm implementing the `commentListener interfac`e and i've managed to get the result inside the **`onCommentEntered`** method. But on **`doneListener`**, which is triggered when the user presses a button finishing the activity, i'm getting null.

Obviously `onCommentEntered` runs after `doneListener`.

Any suggestions on how to get the result on `doneListener`?

```
class MainActivity implements fragment.commentListener{  

static String comment;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addtransaction);
    done=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.done_button);
}

  // called when user presses a button and MainActivity finishes.

public void doneListener(View v){
    // Here i get NULL

    System.out.println(comment);
    finish();
}

 @Override
    public void onCommentEntered(String data) {
             comment=data;
             // Here i get what the user typed
             System.out.println(comment);
    }
}
```

My fragment

```
public class thefragment extends Fragment {

commentListener cListener;
static TextView note;
EditText comment;

public interface commentListener{
    void onCommentEntered(String data);
}

public static thefragment newInstance(){
    return new thefragment ();
}
public thefragment (){
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    cListener=(commentListener) context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    cListener=null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v;
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    comment=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.comment_picker);
    comment.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (!hasFocus) {
                  cListener.onCommentEntered(comment.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of sending a View as a parameter for doneListener method?

Comment: I've declared doneListener on my xml layout as a listener for the button (android:onClick).

Comment: It does't look like you were following the guide. It uses java Interface as listener. So if you want your Activity to be your listener - it should implement a defined Interface and your fragment to use this Interface.

Comment: If you declared in your xml android:onClick="doneListener" then it should work fine....could you post the stack trace please?

Comment: And also why don't you have class MainActivity implements commentListener ?

Comment: I've implemented commentListener on MainActivity.I forgot to add it here.Sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting null" in doneListener. what exactly is null ?

Comment: In my fragment i have an EditText.When user clicks and enters some text, i pass that text to MainActivity.From onCommentEntered (of MainActivity) i get that text and i pass it on variable 'comment'.I am able to print 'comment'  inside onCommentEntered (i get what user typed), but on doneListener 'comment' is empty.

Comment: I understand, but you print the View and not the text - is that what you intended to do ?

Comment: I edited the code before uploading and made i mistake.I wanted to print the 'comment' variable, not the view.Sorry for the confusion.Essentially onCommentEntered runs after doneListener and thus i get null in the first case.

Comment: Could you please copy your XML as well ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102895/discussion-between-gioravered-and-tasgr86).

Comment: I think the problem is caused because i use OnFocusChangeListener for my EditText.In that case onCommentEntered method is called when my MainActivity finishes and 'comment' variable is thus null.
If i switch to OnClickListener for my EditText then onCommentEntered is triggered before MainActivity finishes and i get what user typed on 'comment' as i wanted.
However using onClickListener for my EditText is not an option as it listens only on the second click.Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397609/onclicklistener-listens-only-on-the-second-time

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Interface, as well as implement the same in Fragment. create a method in the interface and override the same in Fragments. While calling the fragment from Activity create an Interface type fragment and call the interface method.

eg:

```
 public class thefragment extends Fragment implement fragmentNofyInterface {
   ...
   @Override
   protected void notify(String txt){
     mTvTxt.setText(txt);
   }
   .....
}

Interface Format

public interface fragmentNofyInterface {
     protected void notify(String txt);
}
```

Activity format

```
class MainActivity implements fragment.commentListener{  
       .....
       private fragmentNofyInterface mFragmentNotifier;

       .........

       thefragment  mFragment = new  thefragment();  
       mFragmentNotifier = (fragmentNofyInterface ) mFragment;
       FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentMngr.beginTransaction().
                            add(R.id.rl_fragment_navigation_container,
                                    mFragment);
       transaction .commit();

      ......

      //Notify the fragment when you required

      mFragmentNotifier.notify("hello world"); 


   }
```

Comment: This is the opposite for what he needs. He wants the Activity to listen to the Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `addTextChangedListener` and `TextWatcher` for my `EditText`, like [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708146/android-setoneditoractionlistener-doesnt-fire),
seems to fix my problem.Now `onCommentEntered` method is called before `doneListener` and thus String `comment`gets whatever was typed in the EditText.Thanks everyone for helping.